# How to return value in ExpressionTree

Tags: c#, expression-trees

i'm trying to do for an expression tree and try to let it return a simple int value. but it not working anymore

```
        var method = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] {typeof(string)});

        var result = Expression.Variable(typeof(int));



        var block = Expression.Block(
            result,
          Expression.Assign(result,Expression.Constant(0)),
            Expression.IfThenElse(Expression.Constant(true),
                Expression.Block(Expression.Call(null, method, Expression.Constant("True")),
                    Expression.Assign(result, Expression.Constant(1))),
                Expression.Block(Expression.Call(null, method, Expression.Constant("False")), Expression.Assign(
                    result, Expression.Constant(0)
                ))),
            result
        );


        Expression.Lambda<Func<int>>(block).Compile()();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not with returning a vaue from the block (you are doing it correctly), but the out of scope variable due to the used wrong `Expression.Block` method overload.

Variable expressions like your `result` must be passed to the block expression using some of the overloads with `IEnumerable<ParameterExpression> variables` argument, for instance

```
    var block = Expression.Block(
        new ParameterExpression[] { result },
        //... (the rest of the sample code unchanged)
    );
```

Comment: Fixed a typo. Also, congrats on 100k, enjoy your swag when it arrives in 6-8 weeks!

Comment: @DavidG Thank you, HNY and coding!

Comment: Congrats Ivan, indeed an inspiration, keep it up

Comment: Thanks @MrinalKamboj, wish you the same.

Comment: thanks @Ivan Stoev. its working now! i forget setup the return parameter at begin of block definition : )